# How to create view in SQLite using INSERT INTO?

Tags: view, sqlite

I'm trying to create view that will summarize data in two tables. Each table have several columns, but they both have NAME and AREA columns. And I want these two columns to be united correspondingly in view. I tried to create view using following query:

```
CREATE VIEW summary AS
INSERT INTO (SELECT Name, SUM(Area) FROM table1 GROUP BY Name)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Name, SUM(Area) FROM table2 GROUP BY Name)
```

But I get the error: `SQL error: near "INSERT": syntax error`. Actually I tried different querys involving INSERT INTO and it seems that CREATE VIEW will not work with INSERT INTO, and INSERT INTO does not accept subquery - only existing table (even temporal) would do.

How to rewrite CREATE VIEW statement to achieve my goal?

Comment: You probably need to use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, not `INSERT`: `CREATE VIEW summary AS SELECT Name, SUM(Area) FROM table1 GROUP BY Name UNION ALL SELECT Name, SUM(Area) FROM table2 GROUP BY Name ;`

Comment: `INSERT` is not used in a view create statement in any dialect of SQL I have heard of - a `VIEW` is (as the name implies) intended to display data only, not for DML operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, not `INSERT`:

```
CREATE VIEW summary AS 
    SELECT Name, SUM(Area) AS Area 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY Name 
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT Name, SUM(Area) 
    FROM table2 
    GROUP BY Name ;
```

If there are values in the `Name` columns that appear in both tables and you want them summarized in one row, you can use this:

```
CREATE VIEW summary3 AS 
   SELECT Name, SUM(Area) AS Area 
   FROM summary 
   GROUP BY Name ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/96cd7/1)**